# add section title in listview

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm using simplecursoradapter with a sql and a listview, how can I add section title in it? My database has a timestamp, in the simplecursoradapter the value is input to the listview directly, but I want to have the timestamp converted to weekday before putting in the listview, how can I do that?

Comment: It seems like you're asking 2 questions here.  It's a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

To add a header you should Use `ListView.addHeaderView(View v)`. To get a date (assuming you are using UNIX time, i.e. `System.currentTimeMillis()`) you can use something like `Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(timeInMillis))`